# Cache items corrupt or mixed up

Tags: asp.net, caching

I have a very strange problem with a website where several objects are cached.
We have a lot of DataTables, strings, booleans and other stuff that are cached for quick fetching in later requests.

Sometimes we get a periodic error where it looks like some of the cache items have been mixed up.
An example of how this shows itself is when a piece of code fetches a DataTable from the cache and then tries to access a certain column of that DataTable.
We then see a yellow screen of death with the exception "Cannot find column [ColumnName]", where "ColumnName" of course is some column name that was supposed to be in the DataTable.
When I inspect the cache item with a little home made tool, I see that a completely different DataTable is in the cache item. It is almost like some of the cache items have been mixed up.

Does anybody have an idea how this happens?

We are not able to reproduce the error. It occurs at apparently random intervals.

Comment: In ASP.NET (framework 3.5), IIS 6.0, I abandonded Cache all together and used either static collections or Session due to random issues that couldn't be reproduced.  When we upgrade to IIS 7 and .NET 4, I may try using it again.

Comment: Its seems that you NOT make good lock and your cache is accessible by different threads.

Comment: Do you use any kind of lock ? when you make or accessible your cache ?

Comment: I use no lock. Neither when I write to the cache or when I get from it.

Comment: @EmKay this is the error then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Whats the issue

When you add items to the cache, you need to lock the process that you create them and added to the cache.

First lets **clarify that the cache is keep a reference to your data**, is not clone them, nether knows whats is not that data ! reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6(VS.71).aspx

Second clarify that the default **session of a page is lock the pages** and is by make most of the request safe because all users lock until a page fully load and send.

### When its appear

So the lock issue may appear when you try to make cache by a thread, or by a handler, or by a page that have session off.

### How to lock

If you use only one pool, then the simple `lock(object){}` can work, if you use many pools then you need to use `mutex()` for lock

You need to lock the full process of making your data if you change them later and still existing on cache, or only the cache reference if you make clone of them.

For example, if you read some data that you have get from the cache, then the time you edit them, if some other read the same cache it will get corrupted data, because the cache is give you a reference to them.

Hope that all this helps.

Comment: The problem was that unstable database connections was used several places in the application, so the problem was not the cache at all.
However, this answer made me a lot wiser on best practices with cache so the code is now even more stable.
Thanks :)